# "Add Dataverse data store" & "Pay-as-you-go with Azure" settings when creating new environments

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, administration, powerapp, power-platform

We want to create 2 power platform environments:

1. one for testing and development
2. the other for production

now the environments will mainly contains:

1. Solutions for connecting Power Apps and Power Automate with SharePoint lists and libraries..

so i am not sure what i need to define inside those 2 settings "Add Dataverse data store" & "Pay-as-you-go with Azure" ??

[image]

per my knowledge since we are going to create solutions, then we will need dataverse... even if our data sources are SharePoint and not Dataverse?

for the Pay-As-You-go >> if i check it >> i will get that we do not have any billing policy:-

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are planning to use the solutions for connecting Power Apps and Power Automate with SharePoint lists and libraries, you will have to set **Add Dataverse data store?** to **Yes**.

You can ignore **Pay-as-you-go with Azure?** option and set it to **No** as it is not required for your development scenarios.

You can read more about Pay-as-you-go with Azure plan in Power Platform at this Microsoft official documentation:

[Pay-as-you-go plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/pay-as-you-go-overview)

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you will involve connecting Power Apps and Power Automate with SharePoint lists and libraries, so you will likely need to add a Dataverse data store to your environments. This will allow you to store metadata for your solutions and manage data relationships. Additionally, you can opt for the Pay-as-you-go with Azure setting, which will allow you to pay for Dataverse usage by the environment instead of requiring 1 GB capacity. To set up Pay-as-you-go, you will need to create a billing policy in the Power Platform admin center using an Azure subscription of your choice, and then specify that billing policy when creating a new environment.

For your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2022wave1/power-platform-governance-administration/power-platform-pay-as-you-go-ability-create-new-environments-without-having-dataverse-capacity-their-tenant#power-platform-pay-as-you-go---create-new-environments-without-having-dataverse-capacity-available-in-the-tenant